# detect and replace value Onkeydown

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I used the override of `OnKeyPress` in `winform TextBox` to replace some input key, in my old project

```
if(e.KeyChar == 'a')
   e.KeyChar = 'b'; // just an example
```

but in wpf I have to use `OnKeyDown` and `e.key` haven't a setter !!

what I have to use in my custom TextBox to change some pressed key ?

Comment: Did you mean `winform Textbox` or `wpf textbox`?

Comment: @keyboardP I have to use it in WPF

Comment: @keyboardP sorry I update my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work.

For **WinForm**:

```
 protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     //newChar will be passed to the base
     char newChar = e.KeyChar;

     if (e.KeyChar == 'a')
     {
         //handle the event and cancel the original key 
         e.Handled = true;

        //get caret position
         int tbPos = this.SelectionStart;

         //insert the new text at the caret position
         this.Text = this.Text.Insert(tbPos, "b");

         //update the newChar
         newChar = 'b';       

         //replace the caret back to where it should be 
         //otherwise the insertion call above will reset the position
         this.Select(tbPos + 1, 0);
     }

     base.OnKeyPress(new KeyPressEventArgs(newChar));
}
```

**Updated based on comment** (I'll leave the above code for anyone using WinForm textboxes)

For **WPF**:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Key newKey = e.Key;

    if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {
        //handle the event and cancel the original key
        e.Handled = true;

        //get caret position
        int tbPos = this.SelectionStart;

        //insert the new text at the caret position
        this.Text = this.Text.Insert(tbPos, "b");

        newKey = Key.B;

        //replace the caret back to where it should be 
        //otherwise the insertion call above will reset the position
        this.Select(tbPos + 1, 0);
    }


    base.OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(e.KeyboardDevice, e.InputSource, e.Timestamp, newKey));
}
```

Comment: can´t he pass a new instance of KeyPressEventArgs to base.OnKeyPress? KeyPressEventArgs has a public ctor to create instances

Comment: I have not tested if that works, but lets see what Akrem says

Comment: but Wpf TextBox haven't a OnKeyPress !

Comment: @Akrem - I've updated the answer for WPF textboxes but it's untested.

Comment: thx :) I asked this question to get a direct action, because I was thinking to use this idea and I thought this wrong :) +1 and accepted answer